# What to seek/avoid in a hosted server monitoring service?

Tags: monitoring, performance-monitoring, performance-tuning, database-performance

I'm looking for hosted monitoring solution (CPU, memory, disk, loads, mysql, replication network etc..)  for a group of servers on Amazon EC2 /Scalr (app, mysql, load balancer).

So far I found http://scoutapp.com ,  http://www.serverdensity.com, http://portal.monitis.com/

Do you know the pros and cons for these services. do you have experience with them? Any other similar services I should look at?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

how about zabbix with http://www.mikoomi.com/ it all open source

Answer (score 1):

How about Circonus:

https://circonus.com/

It's made by the guys over at OmniTI. I've been using it for months and it's an excellent hosted monitoring and trending solution. Prices are very reasonable too. I highly recommend checking it out.

Comment: Just checked it out. It looks more like a pingdom competitor to monitor web pages load time than a serious server bottleneck level monitoring tool

Comment: Not at all, it goes well beyond that. It can use a Nagios-like agent on your systems to report data back to their interface of any shape and size. It's quite a powerful system.